# Bash not redirecting Python multiprocessing output to file when run in background

Tags: python, bash, macos, multiprocessing

For the purposes of running unit tests I want to set up a local SMTP server with Python using the following command:

```
python -c "import smtpd, asyncore; smtpd.DebuggingServer(('127.0.0.1', 8025), None); asyncore.loop()" > test.log &
```

But no output gets written to the `test.log` file.

However, the output does get written when I run:

```
python -c "import smtpd, asyncore; smtpd.DebuggingServer(('127.0.0.1', 8025), None); asyncore.loop()" > test.log` or `python -c "print('TEST')" > test.log &
```

Does this have something to do with asyncore? Or what is going on here?

I'm on Mac OSX with `Python 3.6`.

Edit:
I've attempted to use the `aiosmtpd` module with the following command to start the server:

```
python -m aiosmtpd -n > test.log &
```

This gives the same results. So this does appear to only be an issue when dealing with multiprocessing loops

Edit 2: Simplified commands a little, removing nohup and sudo, same issue remains

Edit 3: To clarify, once I run the server I'm running the following in the interpreter to send the message:

```
import smtplib; server = smtplib.SMTP(host='127.0.0.1', port=8025); server.ehlo(); server.sendmail("sender@test.test", "receiver@test.test", "MESSAGE")
```

Edit 4: I've even tried running the above `asyncore.loop()` in a file with:

```
python test.py > test.log &
```

Still no luck

Comment: nohup should redirect the output to a `nohup.out` file, is that file being created? what happens if you call `python -m aiosmtpd -n &` thus no redirecting the output?

Comment: running `python -m aiosmtpd -n &` outputs correctly to stdout

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `nohup`, it's `sudo`. `sudo` must be asking for your password and then cancelling as it can't ask you while in the background, so, reordering your commands and activating the sudo background flag...

```
sudo -b nohup python -c "import smtpd, asyncore; smtpd.DebuggingServer(('127.0.0.1', 587), None); asyncore.loop()" > test.log
```

`sudo -b` replaces the `&`, because it will run python in the background.

Comment: See my second edit, I've removed nohup and sudo (by changing the port number) from the commands but the issue still remains

Comment: Even running `sudo -b python -m aiosmtpd -n > test.log` doesn't output anything into `test.log`